# Winform C# control not refreshing correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with some of the controls which are being refreshed every 1 second.
Controls being refreshed are 3 progress bars and 3 labels.
But after 52 minutes the lables get wierd and do not show text anymore.

**Tick Event:**

```
private void Timer_SystemInfo_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer_SystemInfo.Stop();
        float CPU_raw = CPUcounter.NextValue();
        if (CPU_raw > 100)
            return;
        int CPU_value = int.Parse(CPU_raw.ToString("0"));
        double RAM_raw = RAMcounter.NextValue();
        int RAM_value = int.Parse(((TotalRAM - RAM_raw) / TotalRAM * 100).ToString("0"));
        AvailableStorage = DriveInformation.AvailableFreeSpace / 1000000;
        double AvailableStorageGB = double.Parse((AvailableStorage / 1000).ToString("0.##"));
        int HDD_value = int.Parse(((TotalStorage - AvailableStorage) / TotalStorage * 100).ToString("0"));

        DriveInfo[] Drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        if (Drives.Count() > 1)
        {
            int cnt = 1;
            try
            {
                foreach (DriveInfo partition in Drives)
                {
                    if (cnt > 1)
                    {
                        double Psize = partition.TotalSize / 1000000;
                        double Asize = partition.AvailableFreeSpace / 1000000;
                        int EXT_value = int.Parse(((Psize - Asize) / Psize * 100).ToString("0"));

                        PB_EXT.Value = EXT_value;
                        LB_extstorage.Text = EXT_value + "% - " + Asize.ToString("0") + " MB free";

                        if (!lbl_ext.Visible)
                        {
                            lbl_ext.Show();
                            LB_extstorage.Show();
                            PB_EXT.Show();
                            PB_EXT.BringToFront();
                        }
                    }
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error when reading external drive" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (lbl_ext.Visible)
            {
                lbl_ext.Hide();
                LB_extstorage.Hide();
                PB_EXT.Hide();
            }
        }
        PB_CPU.Value = CPU_value;
        LB_CPU.Refresh();
        LB_CPU.Text = CPU_value + "%";
        PB_RAM.Value = RAM_value;
        LB_RAM.Text = RAM_value + "%";
        PB_HDD.Value = HDD_value;
        LB_HDD.Text = PB_HDD.Value + "% - " + AvailableStorageGB + " GB free";
        Timer_SystemInfo.Start();
    }
```

And here are the 2 pictures. I think you can notice what happened. It happens after some time (minutes).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNiAu.jpg
and this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/80fnT.jpg

The controls look like this. I hope this is not a problem?
Also, I have one more 1-second timer for refreshing the time/date.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVPqe.png

This is the whole setup:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnbeM.png

**Update 1.0**
I tried to UI update only the CPU label and progress bar. It works without problems. Next, I will try with only RAM update and after that only Storage update.

**Update 2.0**
I removed updating of the progress bar and run it through the night. It seems to work OK. There must be some problem with updating of the progress bar. Is it to thin? The height is 5px. Next test will be making the progress bar higher.

**Update 2.1**
I found out that the height of the progress bar was 5px and the radius was also set to 5px. I removed the radius and unfortunately, PB still causes problems.
Next test is to set the height of the PB to 20px also without the radius.

**Update 3.0**
I strongly suspect a bad PB code. I replaced them with MetroFramework PB and testing at the moment. 93 minutes in debug mode and it looks stable.

Comment: it looks more like it isnt drawing properly - this isnt covered in your code. If you are using the UI thread to to do the work that you're monitoring that would certainly cause this

Comment: @BugFinder I updated to the new code. You can now see how I start the timer and what the tick does. I also changed to update the controls only in the Invoker and other calculation is done in outside UI thread.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()`?

Comment: @i486 The Tick event takes around 1 ms execution or so the stopwatch says. The controls in this Tick event do update every second.  On an occasion, it worked nicely for 50 minutes. So I think Application.DoEvents() would not help, or?

Comment: @NikoLeben Work with tick events does not need separate threads. Try it in main thread without `Invoke()`. See the occupied RAM - when it works 50 minutes, maybe RAM is not freed.

Comment: @i486 I am testing this now. I changed back to Timer from Toolbox and removed the Invoke. I also added few Application.DoEvents() just in case. The memory looks stable between 120 - 220 MB

Comment: Ok. But the processing is on the ui thread.  You would do best to offload it

Comment: @BugFinder I will make a Task.Factory.Startnew(() => {calculation...});
I found out that the problem is with updating of the progress bar. I will try to do some test on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bad progress bar itself. The progress bar crashed after some time. I replaced the progress bar from Bunifu to Metro.